# How to allow registry modification and drive C: modification in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, vsto, excel-2007, office-interop

I've been working on an excel plugin using C# 2008 that modifies the registry and writes temporary files under C:. The plugin is working fine until I upgraded to windows 7 and when I did violation rights exceptions pops up all the time. I am already catching them before and nothing is being caught. I also read on changing the contents of the manifest file but it has no .exe file where I can perform mt.exe on:

Any ideas on how to allow these 2 actions?

Comment: There is no good reason to create temporary files outside the user's temp folder (which *is* accessible). Putting things directly on `C:\` or whatever the system partition is, is extremely ugly. Besides that, I don't think people are likely to accept the "needs admin permission" prompt when it's caused by an excel plugin.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: one nasty problem, which he likely isn't running into seeing as how he's using C# but may be related, is [`tmpfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x7sakw.aspx) on Windows attempts to make the temp files in the root drive (usually `C:`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **Run As Administrator** to get full privileges to modify registry

Then, You can write your temporary files in Temp folder, or User folder by using

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

Comment: How about when I'm debugging it? How can I debug it in Admin mode?

Comment: In Windows 7, http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2009/10/07/visual-studio-alway-run-as-administrator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running inside Excel, it is unrealistic to expect that Excel be run with administrator privileges. Therefore you need to separate the actions that require admin rights into a separate executable, apply the `requireAdministrator` manifest to the executable, and then invoke the executable from your plugin.